# How to send sentences, not single words, to an API and get them send back

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project to convert an old Irish dictionary that uses non-standardised spelling. The objective is to send the non-standardised text to an API that will convert it to standardised spelling.
The user should only have to click a button and the text will be sent behind the scenes to the API. The standardised spelling will return in two seconds and be seen on the webpage.

It sounds easy but is surprisingly difficult. The code for the API is [here](https://github.com/kscanne/caighdean)
The [instructions](https://github.com/kscanne/caighdean/blob/master/API.md) for setting it up is

Here is code, both HTML and JavaScript, for running something similar:

```js
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var form = document.getElementById("IGform");
    form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

      XHR.onreadystatechange = function(event) {
        if (XHR.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
          if (XHR.status == 200) {
            processPairs(JSON.parse(event.target.responseText));
          }
          else {
            var div=document.getElementById("output");
            div.innerHTML=XHR.status.toString()+': '+XHR.statusText;
          }
        }
      };

      XHR.open("POST", "https://cadhan.com/api/intergaelic/3.0");
      XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      XHR.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
      var payload = '';
      var radios = document.getElementsByName('foinse');
      for (var i=0; i<radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
          payload = 'foinse='+radios[i].value+'&teacs=';
          break;
        }
      }
      payload += encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('sourcetext').value);
      XHR.send(payload);
      var div=document.getElementById("output");
      div.innerHTML='<em>Translating...</em>'
    });
  });

  function processPairs(arr) {
    var div=document.getElementById("output");
    var suppress = true;
    div.innerHTML='';
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      t=arr[i][1];
      if (t=="\\n") {
        div.innerHTML+='<br/>';
        suppress = true;
      }
      else {
        if (suppress==false && !t.match(/^[.,\/;”:!?%})]$/)) {
          div.innerHTML+=" ";
        }
        suppress = (t.match(/^[“\/$(\[#{]$/)!==null);
        div.innerHTML+=t;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<form id="IGform">
  <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="sourcetext" name="teacs" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
  <br/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
  <input type="reset" value="Clear"></input>
  <br/><br/>
  Source language:<br/>
  <input type="radio" name="foinse" value="gd" checked>Scottish Gaelic</input><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="foinse" value="gv">Manx Gaelic</input><br/>
  <input type="radio" name="foinse" value="ga">Pre-Standard Irish</input><br/>
</form>
<hr/>
<div id="output"></div>
```

What I am trying to create instead of a form is a text that is already formatted in HTML. The user can click a button and the JavaScript will send the text to the API and then the standardised spelling will be provided pretty quickly thereafter.

I hope that it is easy to understand. Any help with this matter would really appreciated.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Here's the short version, using fetch instead: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4km7jtux/

Comment: The problem is that the code that I provided there is based on a form. Users have to type something into a form and send it. I want to create a code that will send text that is already provided in HTML format and that will be sent and returned to the HTML page. The JavaScript will cause the text to be converted into standardised spelling.

Comment: If anyone is interested, you can use this entry from the Irish dictionary and see how it gets changed to the standardised spelling. "meidhir, caitheamh aimsire, aoibhneas
Chuirfeadh iarthar Chiarraighe ábhacht ar chroidhe aonne lé n-a bhreághthacht: aoibhneas agus éirighe croidhe. Ag ábhacht seadh bhí na buachaillidhe nuair goirtigheadh duine aca: ag déanamh seóidh. Bímíd bailighthe sa tigh seo gach oidhche ag ábhacht: ag déanamh cuideachtan, grinn a’s seóidh. Scéal ró-stuama dho seadh é chun ábhachta do dhéanamh de .i. chun magaidh do dhéanamh de."

Comment: Hello @ChrisG what is different in your code to what I published?

Comment: @SeanánÓCoistín are you looking for `innerHTML`?

Comment: Perhaps. I am not sure how this is going to work. It should be just text and not a form.